# How can I change the ownership of an API Doc in apiary.io?

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

What I want is change the main email associated with an API Doc, so when I share the doc with others people they see that new email and not the mine. That new email have an apiary.io, that is why I'm talking about ownership transferring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted the support and they tell me that what I need can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here. We ended up copying and pasting the docs from one team member's account to another, then deleting the old one. Only took a couple minutes.